# Is there anything wrong with the way that this C++ header is laid out?

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include "LudoCore/Singleton.h"

class LudoTimer : public Singleton<LudoTimer>
{
    friend class Singleton<LudoTimer>;

public:
    void Update();
    void ShortenDay();
    void LengthenDay();
    UINT64 GetDeltaTime() const;
    float GetPercentageOfDayElapsed() const;

private:
    LudoTimer();
    ~LudoTimer();

    UINT64 GetTickCount64() const;
    UINT64 GetElapsedSeconds() const;

    UINT64 m_DeltaTime;

    // Tick Count
    UINT64 m_CurrFrameTick;
    UINT64 m_LastFrameTick;

    int m_SecondsInADay;
    static const int SHORTEST_POSSIBLE_DAY = 60;
    static const int LONGEST_POSSIBLE_DAY = 86400;
    static const int CHANGING_INTERVAL = 600;
};
```

To me, the above code looks normal.  However, I'm new to C++ so I may be missing some nuance.  I'm getting a bunch of compiler errors from it, such as:

> error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

and

> error C2236: unexpected 'class'
>   'LudoTimer'. Did you forget a ';'?

What gives!

Comment: Those errors wouldn't happen to include line numbers, would they?

Comment: Also, Singleton.h may be important. If it isn't too long, could you post it also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look in the other header (LudoCore/Singleton.h). The second error implies that the error is before the `class LudoTimer` declaration at the top.

My guess is that Singleton.h defines a class, and there's a missing ';' after that class definition.

Answer (score 3):

The error is probably in `LudoCore/Singleton.h` or something else included earlier.  Make sure your `class` definitions have `;` semicolons after them and all that.

Quick test: comment out the `#include` and stick a `template<class C> class Singleton;` predeclaration there instead.  If the compiler now complains about incomplete types, I'm right, and if not, post more details.

Comment: Okay, same thing.  I should have known you were using MSVC from the error messages and `#pragma once` ...  Anyhow, the problem may not be `Singleton.h` but it's definitely something included earlier.  Post more sources and complete compiler output, please.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the following compiles fine for me, so the error is very likely not in the code you showed us. I suggest you have a second look at [Mike's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691100/1691135#1691135) that there is an error in `Singleton.h`.

```
//#include "LudoCore/Singleton.h"
#include <windows.h>

template< typename T >
class Singleton {};

class LudoTimer : public Singleton<LudoTimer>
{
    friend class Singleton<LudoTimer>;
public:
    void Update();
    void ShortenDay();
    void LengthenDay();
    UINT64 GetDeltaTime() const;
    float GetPercentageOfDayElapsed() const;
private:
    LudoTimer();
    ~LudoTimer();

    UINT64 GetTickCount64() const;
    UINT64 GetElapsedSeconds() const;

    UINT64 m_DeltaTime;

    // Tick Count
    UINT64 m_CurrFrameTick;
    UINT64 m_LastFrameTick;

    int m_SecondsInADay;
    static const int SHORTEST_POSSIBLE_DAY = 60;
    static const int LONGEST_POSSIBLE_DAY = 86400;
    static const int CHANGING_INTERVAL = 600;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if LudoTimer is declared at the point that it is used by Singleton and if a forward declaration would help? I didn't need one in VisualStudio 2005 and like sbi I could compile the code by supplying a declaration of Singleton. If I added a simplistic implementation I could even do:

```
    LudoTimer* timer = Singleton<LudoTimer>::instance();
```

One more thing:

```
    error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'LudoTimer'. Did you forget a ';'?
```

You could try adding a semicolon on a blank line after the #include to answer this question. If it helps then you can show that there is a problem in the header file without needing to edit it.